# R Shiny: Change row in uiOutput that contains text in HTML()

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using renderUI in server.R in the following way:

```
  output$optstatus <- renderUI({
    HTML(paste("ONE","\n","TWO","\n","THREE"))
  })
```

Even though I'm adding the \n -signs, all the the text is on the same row. How can I get the row change commands working in uiOutput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace "\n" by a html tag [< br>](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) as follows:

```
output$optstatus <- renderUI({
          HTML(paste("ONE","<br>","TWO","<br>","THREE"))
        })
```